# select li element based on the ul

Tags: javascript, jquery

how I can select the second ul li element, I have this structure:
**HTML**

```
<ul>
       <li></li>
       <ul>
           <li>I want to select this</li>
      </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: I've answer as per your HTML only.

Comment: Try my answer with multiple options

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly your HTML is invalid. You cannot have `ul` as a child of another `ul`. It must be within an `li`. Also the text within the `ul` must also be within a `li`.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>I want to select this</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

To then select this in jQuery you can use:

```
$('ul > li > ul > li:first');
```

You could also use the less strict: `ul ul li:first`, depending on how rigidly you need to adhere to the HTML structure you defined.

Answer (score 0):

the structure you provided is not proper, the child `<ul>` tag should go inside an `<li>` tag.
then the structure will be like

```
<ul class="ul">
    <li></li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>I want to select this </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

then you can get that child `<ul>` using jquery as

```
$(".ul li ul");
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Why not than `$(".ul ul");`?

Answer (score 0):

First you must add a class or an id to your parent ul :

```
<ul class="root">
    <li></li>
    <ul>
        I want to select this <li></li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Then, either your choose to select the 2nd one because it will always be the second (index 1) :

```
$(".root").find("li").eq(1)
```

Or you add a class to your `<li>`:

```
<ul class="root">
    <li></li>
    <ul>
        I want to select this <li class="myLi"></li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

And then

```
$(".root").find(".myLi")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet with multiple options.

```js
console.log($('ul > ul > li:eq(0)').text());
//OR
console.log($('ul').find('ul > li:eq(0)').text());
//OR
console.log($('ul').children('ul').find('li:eq(0)').text());
//OR
console.log($('ul > ul').find('li:eq(0)').text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul><b>First ul</b>
      <li>First li</li>
      <ul> <b>Second ul</b>
          <li>First li in second ul</li>
      </ul>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`querySelector`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp) to do that. Check below example.

```js
var li = document.querySelector('ul ul li');

console.log(li.innerHTML);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Not this</li>
  <ul>
    <li>I want to select this</li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: P.S: This will work only on simple complexity and single  `li`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan : But user haven't specified any other complexity

Comment: That's why I used `P.S:`